# Adding dots(.) after certain characters from mysql response

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, substr

I have a random mysql response. I need to display the response in smarty template. I want to add dots in one column, but don't know how to do it. Here is my code:

```
function homepage_profiles()
{

        $sql = "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tbl_profile
        WHERE
            bz_pro_show = 'Y'
        ORDER BY
            RAND()  
    ";
    $res = $this->db->returnArrayOfObject($sql, $pgin = 'no', $odr='no');
    return $res;
 }


$res_pro = $this->homepage_profiles();

$this->assign_values('rand_pro',$res_pro);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use Smarty with something like `{$rand_pro|truncate:50:'...'}` or MySql with  something like `SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(about_me, 50),"...") as about_me_trunc`
...

Answer (score 1):

```
$var['column'] = substr($var['column'], 0, 50)." ... ";
```

Comment: actually I want add dots(...). Suppose I have a column called about_me and it has 100 charecters . Since its too long I want to limit its size to 50 charecters and add the dots after it.And yes its a random and I need tto display it in smarty too.

Comment: thnaks genesis. But since its a random output array I can not send them individually .

Comment: @SurajHazarika: array_map() ?

Answer (score 0):

you can change your sql from `select * ...` to `select col_a + '.', col_b, col_c ...` .

NB: `+` operator is mysql-specific; other database servers use `||` or you can use `CONCAT()` to ensure portability.